# calculate the specific function

Tags: python, math

```
import math


if x == 2 ** (((x-1000)/10)^(1/2)):
    print( x)
```

I am trying to write a function to solve the function N = 10 * (Log2 N)^2+1000, but it does not work, can someone help me to fix it?

Comment: The "function" you wrote doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem stated in your question. I think you need to learn a few Python fundamentals first. There is no need to initialize variables, for example. And you don't need an `if` statement here but a simple assignment. What you do need is a value to compute (`N` in your example). Check out the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: the function I wrote is the simplified version of the function

Comment: It looks like the inverse of the function, but it would need at least another variable (`x` will never be equal to `2 ** (((x-1000)/10)^(1/2))`), and you'd need a strategy of finding a matching value for `N`. Something iterative perhaps, if your goal is to solve this problem without using `math.log()`.

Answer (score 1):

Or iterate the function some times, provided it is by chance a fixed point iteration

```
from math import log

func = lambda x : 10*log(x,2)**2 + 1000
x=1000
for _ in range(15): x = func(x); print "%.12f" % x
```

which gives the output

```
1993.168564084178
2201.401890990801
2233.034094200055
2237.609428257210
2238.266536460564
2238.360814103042
2238.374338474385
2238.376278539726
2238.376556840441
2238.376596762423
2238.376602489195
2238.376603310695
2238.376603428538
2238.376603445443
2238.376603447868
```

which looks like slightly less than one correct digit gained per iteration.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO:

This is what you are looking for based on this equation:function N = 10 * (Log2 N)^2+1000

```
import math
def funct_try(x):
    return (10*(math.log(x,2)**2)+1000)

funct_try(100)
```

answer would be 1441.4082507040794

Comment: why did  you take 100 as input? is that the answer for x?

Comment: yes 100 is an input, and yes x is 100 so function gives value of the function

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand what you actually want.Also the code you wrote doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem stated in your question.
Assuming you are having problem to understand how to use the log function:

lets say you want to calculate log function with base 2 then:

```
import math
print(math.log(8,2))
```

Output:

```
3.0
```

Assuming that helped.NOw,let's try your function;it should look something like this:

```
import math
def function_name(N):
    print(10*(math.pow(math.log(N,2),2))+1000)

function_name(110) #here I called the above function with a value 100
```

Output:

```
1459.8683956421526
```

Comment: Yes it solves the equation.Like I said ,110 is just a sample value to demonstrate you.